# Picard successive approximations for a system of linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We saw in class how to use Picard's successive approximation method to approximate a solution for an ODE by "guessing" $\Phi_0$ and then improving the guess using the formula: 
$$\Phi_{n+1}(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f[t, \Phi_n(t)]dt$$ 
Until now I only saw it applied to simple first-order differential equations, but now I have a system of linear equations:
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\dot{x} = y\\ 
\dot{y} = -x - \frac{8}{5}y
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
For which I'm supposed to calculate approximations using this method. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Scroll down to "Extension to First Order Systems in 2D" [here](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/picarditerationmod.html). (I haven't checked it carefully, but at first glance, it looks like it has an obvious typo)

Comment: Note that this is the problem $\dot{X} =AX$ where $X=(x,y)$ and $AX=A(x,y)=(y,-x-8/5 y)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks! don't you want to write it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll down to "Extension to First Order Systems in 2D" [here](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/picarditerationmod.html), where the iteration method for a system of two linear equations is described. Note that you'll need some initial values for the method.

Beware, though, there is an obvious typo in the link: in equation (8) there,  the formula for $X_{n+1}(t)$ should read $X_{n+1}(t)=\color{maroon}{x_0}+\int_{t_0}^t f\bigl(s, X_n(s), Y_n(s)\bigr)\, ds$.